# How to use ModernWPF Programaticially

Tags: wpf, python.net

[ModernWPF](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf) is a great project, as it restyles my WPF app in modern UI style. The docs tell what XAML changes to be done to activate the styling. Unfortunately I am working with an application that is not XAML based (Python.NET).

I tried already to add the dictionaries programaticially like:

```
    app = Application()
    app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(ModernWpf.ThemeResources())
    app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(ModernWpf.Controls.XamlControlsResources())
    app.Run(win)
```

The main window `win` is created via XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
    Title="Enterprisey-FireDrop Express" Width="640" Height="480"
    ui:WindowHelper.UseModernWindowStyle="True">
   ...
</Window>
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

In C# the following seems to work, but I'm not sure if the same can be done in Python since I don't know Python at all:

```
var app = new Application();

var themeResources = new ModernWpf.ThemeResources();
((ISupportInitialize)themeResources).BeginInit();
app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(themeResources);
((ISupportInitialize)themeResources).EndInit();

app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ModernWpf.Controls.XamlControlsResources());
app.Run(new MainWindow());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get it work with the modification. But I am curious: the only change (compared to my coe) is enclosing the addition of ``ModernWpf.ThemeResources()`` in a BeginInit/EndInit sequence. According to this docs this is only a (not necessary) optimization. Is there anything about it I missed?